# invoking python compiler from within java

Tags: java, python, invoke

I'm trying to run a Python program from within Java using the following statement

> Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python " + file);

Where file is a string "c:\user\test.py"

It throws me an exception

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

I made sure my system variable has an entry pointing to my python home directory.

please help

Comment: what happens if you type "python c:\user\test.py" in the cmd, while not being at that location?

Comment: it does successfully compile if done from cmd

Comment: please say exactly what string do you assign to the `file`?

Comment: C:\\users\\chaitu\\desktop\\test.py

Comment: Works for me, for some reason, it can't seem to find your file. Try 

`System.out.println((new File("C:\\users\\chaitu\\desktop\\test.py").exists()))`
For debug reasons

Comment: @Flyingfirepig returns true

Comment: Hmm, getting more and more puzzling...
Try replacing the word "python " with the string to your python exe, eg "C:\\Python33\\python.exe "? And are you running the latest Java version?

Comment: Bingo ! it did work giving the path !! thanks a ton literally spent the whole day with it !! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting this for future reference (And so the question can be marked solved), the problem was for some reason, Java didn't like that you were trying to run python by calling it python, and it wanted you to do

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Path\\To\\Python.exe " + file);
```